# Use ibidtracker with alphabetic style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to know if it's possible to use the `ibidtracker` option in combination with  `citestyle=alphabetic` in `biblatex`. Something like this:

```
\usepackage[
    citestyle=alphabetic,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    sortcites,ibidtracker]{biblatex}
]
```

is not working. Maybe, I got it all wrong...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: I thought you had to use `ibidtracker=true'.

Comment: @claudio: got it @cryptic0: No, you can omit that, the only presence of any boolean option assumes this option is set to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work right out of the box, as `alphabetic.cbx` doesn't define anything related to ibid. The following, added to your preamble, should do the trick, but I haven't tested it:

```
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbool{cbx:loccit}

\DeclareBibliographyOption{ibidpage}[true]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
    \ifloccit
      {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
      {}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
```

I borrowed and modified many of these definitions from `authoryear-icomp.cbx`, included with a standard Biblatex install. It also adds a new bibliography option, `ibidpage` which you should probably use if you're going to rely on ibid citations.

Comment: I don't have latex installed on the computer I'm working on right now but will definitely give it a try. thanks

Comment: Epilogue: I use your answer to modify the alphabetic.cbx file, use it with `ibidtracker=constrict,sortcites,pagetracker,ibidpage` and it works!

Comment: I'm glad it works out for you! Make sure you're careful modifying the style files included with Biblatex, as each update will overwrite your modifications.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, thanks for pointing that out.